# Clob field not populated in object in grailsChange changeset using grails DSL

Tags: grails, groovy, liquibase

I am making my first migration script that involves the use of the Groovy/Grails DSL.  It looks like this:

```
import my.package.MyObject
import my.package.MyObjectUtil
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

databaseChangeLog = {

  changeSet(author: 'wheresjim', id: '1387238199-1')  {
    comment {'Sets the timestamp in each MyObject where null using the message text'}
    grailsChange {
      change {

        MyObjectUtil myObjectUtil = new MyObjectUtil()

        def criteria = MyObject.where {
          isNull("timestamp")
        }

        def PAGESIZE = 10
        int numRows = criteria.count()
        int pages = Math.ceil(numRows / PAGESIZE)

        (pages..0).each { page ->

          int offset = PAGESIZE * page + PAGESIZE

          def data = criteria.list(offset: offset, max: PAGESIZE, sort: 'id', order: 'asc')

          data.each { MyObject myObject ->

            Date timestamp = new Date(0L)

            try {
              def thisMessage = myObjectUtil.createMyObjectFromMessage(myObject.messageText)
              String dateStr = thisMessage.messageIdentification?.timestamp
              timestamp = dateStr ? DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(dateStr).getTime() : timestamp
            } catch (Exception e) {
              // Do nothing, this will be logged in the finally which catches another error condition
            } finally {
              if (timestamp == new Date(0L)) {
                log.warn "Error attempting to set timestamp in MyObject ${myObject.id}, setting to $eventDateTime"
              }
            }

            myObject.timestamp = timestamp
            myObject.save(flush: true)
          }            
          log.warn "Updated ${myObject.id}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `MyObject.messageText` is a clob in the database, and to my knowledge, there has been no effort to lazily load it.

I should note that this exact script works (it can find the clob text) using the grails console plugin on the app.

Comment: As a generic advice, try to execute a more simplified version first, maybe it is only some simple difference between the two execution environments.

Comment: I actually had, at one point I was just trying to log the value of the clob field.

Answer (score 0):

In **MyObject** make sure your have the following lines:

```
static mapping = {
        messageText type: 'text'
    }
```

Comment: I have that.  I did figure out that the version of liquibase that the grails migrate plugin is 2.05, which is out of date, and from what I read, there are some fixes for blob/clob handling with liquibase 3.x.